# Ektorp - @DocumentReference not working

Tags: couchdb, ektorp

I am a newbee to Couch and I found lazy-fetching interesting. So I was trying that out but probably due to something wrong I did, it doesn't work and I can't figure out what is wrong. I referred http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d100e394. I get the error below. (I am able to read the docs separately but not by document referencing). Any help would be much appreciated. I'm using ektorp version 1.4.1.

```
09:51:03.581 [main] DEBUG org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector - Querying CouchDb view at /employee/_design/Employee/_view/ektorp_docrefs_addresses?startkey=%5B%22222%22%2C%22addresses%22%5D&endkey=%5B%22222%22%2C%22addresses%22%2C%7B%7D%5D&include_docs=true.
Exception in thread "main" org.ektorp.DocumentNotFoundException: nothing found on db path: /employee/_design/Employee/_view/ektorp_docrefs_addresses?startkey=%5B%22222%22%2C%22addresses%22%5D&endkey=%5B%22222%22%2C%22addresses%22%2C%7B%7D%5D&include_docs=true, Response body: {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
    at org.ektorp.http.StdResponseHandler.createDbAccessException(StdResponseHandler.java:40)
    at org.ektorp.http.StdResponseHandler.error(StdResponseHandler.java:68)
    at org.ektorp.http.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:110)
    at org.ektorp.http.RestTemplate.getUncached(RestTemplate.java:27)
    at org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector.executeQuery(StdCouchDbConnector.java:431)
    at org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector.queryView(StdCouchDbConnector.java:423)
    at org.ektorp.impl.docref.ViewBasedCollection.loadSetResult(ViewBasedCollection.java:69)
    at org.ektorp.impl.docref.ViewBasedCollection.loadFromBackReferences(ViewBasedCollection.java:50)
    at org.ektorp.impl.docref.ViewBasedCollection.initialize(ViewBasedCollection.java:102)
    at 
org.ektorp.impl.docref.LazyLoadingViewBasedCollection.invoke(LazyLoadingViewBasedCollection.java:27)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.size(Unknown Source)
    at com.poc.main.Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

My test files are below.

Employee doc

```
{
   "_id": "222",
   "_rev": "1-32d4d52d4ea11b521b1e366959ce5557",
   "name": "Mariamma",
   "age": 21
}
```

Address doc

```
{
   "_id": "ad1",
   "_rev": "2-39f3162e0fc63ed5526adda5ae496291",
   "employeeId": 222,
   "addressLine1": "555 Randolph",
   "city": "Chicago"
}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee extends CouchDbDocument {
  private String name;

  private int age;

  @DocumentReferences(backReference = "employeeId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.NONE)
  private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
// getters and setters
}
```

Address.java

```
public class Address extends CouchDbDocument {

  private String employeeId; 

  private String addressLine1;

  private String addressLine2;

  private String city;

  private String State;

  private String zipCode;
// getters and setters
}
```

EmployeeDao.java

```
public class EmployeeDao {

  private final CouchDbConnector db;

  public EmployeeDao() {
    db = getEmployeeDatabaseConnector();
  }

  public CouchDbConnector getEmployeeDatabaseConnector() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new StdHttpClient.Builder().build();
    CouchDbInstance couchDbInstance = new StdCouchDbInstance(httpClient);
    CouchDbConnector connector = new StdCouchDbConnector("employee", couchDbInstance);
    connector.createDatabaseIfNotExists();
    return connector;
  }

  public Employee read(String employeeId) {
    return this.db.get(Employee.class, employeeId);
  }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EmployeeDao dao = new EmployeeDao();
    Employee employee = dao.read("222");
    System.out.println(employee.getName());
    System.out.println(employee.getAddresses().size()); // this line throws error.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your stack trace

```
... Response body: {"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

This suggests that the view `/_design/Employee/_view/ektorp_docrefs_addresses` isn't there.

**Update**

[Chapter 6 of the Ektorp Reference Docs](http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d100e689) talks about view generation. It looks like you are not created it yourself and have not told Ektorp to do it for you.

You should look at creating a repository class for `Employee` by extending `CouchDbRepositorySupport` and then calling `initStandardDesignDocument()` on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the ektorp documentation doesn't mention anything about creating view. Are you suggesting that I'll have to create a view to get DocumentReferencing work?

Comment: I've dug into the docs a little and provided some more detail.